# Remove an element's class attribute with Hpricot

Tags: html, ruby, hpricot

How do I do it? E.g.,

```
<span class="selected" id="hi">HELLO</span>
```

should become

```
<span id="hi">HELLO</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
span = Hpricot(some_html) % "span#hi"
span.remove_attribute("class")
```